# Activated event in baseform doesn't trigger

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

enter code hereI've built a winform MDI application based on two baseforms, a listform with a grid (_ListForm) and a dataform to display the child data (_DataForm).

When I load an inherited dataform into the MDI, the activated event from the base-form (_DataForm) is triggered and some properties are automatically set. When I load an inherited listform (_ListForm) into the MDI, the activated event is *not* triggered.

My childform doesn't have an (overrided) activated event, there is no significant difference in the two forms, just one triggers the event, one doesn't.

- I've added the eventhandler in code and/or with the designer : no
  trigger
- I've added a new activated event in the childform and called
  base.onActivated(e) : no trigger

For now I moved some of the code into the textchanged event (which also occurs once), but why is this Activated-event not being triggered?

Can add tons of code-samples if needed, but not sure what to post.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, it's the same with the LoadEvent - doesn't trigger in any way.

EDIT: Sources as per request:

_BaseForm : font and general background (no events)

```
public partial class _BaseForm : Form
{
    public _BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

_ListForm : grid and buttons

```
public partial class _ListForm : _BaseForm
{
    public _ListForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Activated += new EventHandler(_ListForm_Activated);
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;

        this.grid1.UltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns.ClearUnbound();
        this.grid1.UltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowAddNew = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.AllowAddNew.No;
        this.grid1.UltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowDelete = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.False;
        this.grid1.UltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowUpdate = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.False;
        this.grid1.UltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Override.CellClickAction = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellClickAction.RowSelect;

        this.grid1.PopulateGridColumns += new FB.Windows.Controls.Grid.PopulateGridColumnsEventHandler(grid1_PopulateGridColumns);
        this.grid1.UltraGrid.InitializeLayout += new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventHandler(UltraGrid_InitializeLayout);
        this.grid1.RowSelected += new FB.Windows.Controls.Grid.RowSelectedEventHandler(grid1_RowSelected);
    }
```

_ListForm event (either in designer or code from ctor):

```
    this.Activated += new System.EventHandler(this._ListForm_Activated);
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this._ListForm_Load);
```

The event itself:

```
private void _ListForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (AutoSearchOnOpen)
    {
        button1_Click(sender, e);
        this.grid1.Focus();
        this.ActiveControl = this.grid1;
    }
    else
    {
        this.textBox1.Focus();
        this.ActiveControl = this.textBox1;
    }
}
```

I know the Click inside the activated event will fire each time it's activated, but for now that doesn't matter: the main problem is: the whole event wont fire. Although the event in the _DataForm (also inherited from _BaseForm) *is* fired.

Comment: What are the exact types for your MDI children? Let's also see the code for the events you mention and the code that wires them up.

Comment: What do you mean by types? PS the source-samples show both the activated event in the code and in the designer - but there is actually just one - I either bind the event in the designer (and comment the code) or I bind the event in code and remove the designer-bind.

Comment: The code sample you have should work (It would be nice to see your InitializeComponent method). At this point, I think you should backup your _ListForm files and then comment out all the grid and extra code so that you're left with just a blank _ListForm and see if that fires your events. If so, slowly comment stuff back in.

Comment: The InitializeComponent method is the Windows Form Designer generated code. Nothing really exciting there, just positioning etc. Like you suggested: I tried to comment and un-comment all the code - the grid seems to be the problem - whenever the grid is placed and hooked to events on the form, the Load event doesn't fire. I've created a workaround for it for the mean time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the grid (3rd party control) overloads (hijacks) the activated and loaded events for the form and don't trigger the base event after the original event.